# Best way to identify which button was pressed for method logic

Tags: java, button, swt

I have a method that is used for two different actions.  The actions are identified by which button the user presses.

I am using a boolean to identify the button press.

```
PDFButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
   public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
      buildArray(true);
   }
});

PlotButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
   public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
      buildArray(false);
   }
});

public void buildArray(boolean buttonId) {
   get indexs etc...
   if(true) {
      PDF.getInstance.buildArray(index);
   }
   else { 
      Plot.getInstance.buildArray(index);
   }
 }
```

Does this seem to be the best way to do this?

**EDIT** Typo in button snippet pasted.  There are 2 buttons not one.
What I am trying to do is set a condition in the IF logic, so I know which button was pushed to activate the buildArray method.

```
public void buildArray() {
   get indexs, mode code.....
   if**(button press equals PDFButton)** {
      PDF.getInstance.buildArray(index);
   }
   else { 
      Plot.getInstance.buildArray(index);
   }
 }
```

I know one way would be to create a separate method similar to buildArray.  Then each button would execute their own method.

```
PDFButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
   public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
      PDFbuildArray(true);
   }
});

PlotButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
  public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
      PlotbuildArray(false);
  }
});
```

But I want to consolidate as mush code as possible.

Comment: `if(true)` is always `true`, did you mean that?

Comment: What do you mean "which button the user pushes"?  You hooked up selection listeners to the *same* button...  Is there a second button somewhere?

Comment: no this is about the worst way to do it possible; that is if your code made logical sense, which it doesn't

Comment: @EdwardThomson I didn't notice this is the same button :D

Comment: @EdwardThomson That is a typo in the placing snippets of code.  It is a PDF button and Plot button.  There are two buttons, not one.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ may actually be the best place for this.

Comment: You could extend make your listener (SelectionAdapter) to accept information about button..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Action Event getSource().getText().  So the method ended up looking like this.

```
 ublic void getSelectedTableData(SelectionEvent e) {
  int[] row = viewer.getTable().getSelectionIndices();
  Arrays.sort(row);
  if (row.length > 0) {
     for(int i = row.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(((Button) e.getSource()).getText() == "Plotting")   
           AplotPlotDataModel.getInstance().buildPlotArray(row[i]);
        else {
           AplotPDFDataModel.getInstance().buildArray(row[i]);
        }
     }
  }
 }
```

Comment: I think your previous solution was superior.  You're comparing strings with `==`, which is not what you want to do.  Nor would you want to compare strings at all, since that would be slow.  Your `boolean` approach from before was a fine solution, or you could look at the button's `ID`.

Comment: This is not a good way of handling events. Adding separate listeners to each button will make your application faster. You dont need to compare button ids or button text.

Answer (score -1):

Have you read the Swing Tutorial?  It has examples about how to do this, usually with setActionCommand() and getActionCommand() IIRC.

Also, there are at least two bugs in your code.

- First, your current code doesn't ever set the array value back to false, so every time a button is pressed, all previously-pressed buttons will also execute.  Unless this is what what you want...
- Second, just like the first, if the buttons are pressed too quickly, the second button press may execute before the first button press code changes the state back to false.  Unless you add a synchronized block, there will be a timing condition that behaves as described in my first bullet.

Comment: I don't know how Swing works, but in SWT, there are no timing issues like what you describe.  Your UI code runs on the UI thread.

Comment: @atk not using Swing.  The code is written in SWT.